# Could not create iOS build summary report (Errors and warnings) in Jenkins with or without Fastlane

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I am using Jenkins and Fastlane for CICD pipeline for my iOS Project. Before we were using Xcode server that provides a direct API using which i exported the build summary(Compilation Errors, Warnings from Xcode). 
But now with Jenkins or fastlane i am not able to do it since i couldn't find any API that generates this report.

For Code Analysis i am using swiftlint. It is generating code analysis report only and it is not showing the default warnings like deprecations etc. in Jenkins. So i understood i cannot use the code analysis tool for this purpose.

Is there any way with which i could generate the Warnings and Errors report in Jenkins? For all the actions like incrementing build number, executing test cases, code signing, generating binary etc. i have written separate lanes in my fastfile.

Comment: I am able to generate Warnings Graph using Warnings plugin and clang LLVM but unable to export it to json or xml. For errors report still couldn't find anything :(

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to generate warnings report in Jenkins. We need to

- Install **Warnings** plugin in jenkins,
- Add a **post build step** to scan compiler warnings,
- Select Clang LLVM as parser.

A trend graph for warnings will be shown and a remote API is available to use the report elsewhere.

But couldn't find anything on the errors though.